TV Movie about a Nazi who pretends to be Jewish, ends up an Israeli general
This movie is from the 1980s.
In it, there is a Nazi concentration camp commandent who shaves his head, tattooes himself, and pretends to be a Jewish prisoners as the Allied Forces liberate the camp.
He goes to Israel where he becomes a national hero as an Israeli general - however, he is suspected by his son, years later, to be a Nazi war criminal.

Sounds like the mini-series Pursuit (AKA Twist of Fate) from 1989:

SS-Lieutenant Colonel Helmut Von Schreader conceives an unusual plan to escape the aftermath of the Second World War by disguising himself as a Jewish Concentration Camp victim. Under the alias of Ben Grossman, Von Schreader is liberated from the camps and immigrates to Palestine where he joins the Zionist movement. Twenty five years later, living as a hero of Israel and a General in the Israeli Army, the underground SS organization ODESSA locates Von Schreader and orders to him to again serve the cause of the Third Reich. 


